# Display images on all android devices

Tags: android, image, screen, image-size

in my android application, I want to display some images of plants (i have more than 100 of them) a i also want to support different screen sizes, but my problem is i can not have images for every screen density in res/drawable folder, because size of my application horribly increase. Is there any solution how to do this? (maybe in code) Thanks a lot.

Comment: create 9patch images so that you can reuse the image for diff-diff resolution

Comment: srry...i did not specify what kind of images i have...they are images of plants so i guess i can not use 9patch

Comment: How do you want to display them? In a grid, in a list, just show an image full screen, or how?

Comment: the screen should looks like herbarium sheet, something like this [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4bMt71BxFiga2RTMHp1SEJrX28/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to have the text wrap around the image. You could best achieve this using [this library](https://code.google.com/p/android-flowtextview/).

As for the images, you would only need to store them at a size that looks good on the largest devices you are looking to support. For the other devices, you would just scale those down. If you're going to use the above library, you might need to set the following parameters on the `ImageView` in the XML file to have it scale down correctly:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
```

Note that you will need to fiddle around with these (especially the weight) so that you get the best fit for your application.

**EDIT**: To conform to your requirement in the comment, the best way to go would be to use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). This does mean you will need to create `HTML` code for your articles, which would completely change the question.

What you could try is to have a `LinearLayout` surrounding the image and add `TextView` objects to it programatically. There are good chances that this will look bad depending on the amount of text you will be adding.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know about this library, it is very useful, I found only very easy example how to use this library, I've tried it... but i need to do something like on this [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4bMt71BxFigVkZUV2dJT09XTm8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: it worked like a charm, many thanks, you saved me a lot of time